# Getting outofmemoryerror while downloading images to a coverflow for an android app

Tags: android, file, inputstream, coverflow

Through web service i am  writing each image in to a JPG file(in sdcard- "mnt/sdcard/img.jpg") and showing the images in to a coverflow view.i am getting the first image but when it comes to the second and other images i am getting outofmemoryerrorr.

below i have given the code to get the image from url

```
public Bitmap getImageDirectHit(String directHitUrl){

    Bitmap bmImg;
         String fileUrl=directHitUrl;
          URL myFileUrl =null;          
          try {
               myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
              bmImg = null;
               HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
               conn.setDoInput(true);
               conn.connect();
               //int length = conn.getContentLength();
               InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
               //conn.disconnect();
  //                   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
  //                   ByteArrayBuffer byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
  //                   int current = 0;
  //                   while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
  //                        byteArrayBuffer.append((byte) current);
  //                   }
  //                   

            File nf = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nf);
            //byte[] buf = new byte[2048]; 
            //int n; 
           // fos.write(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);



            byte[] bufu=new byte[20];
            int len = 0;
            while((len = is.read(bufu))>0) {
                fos.write(bufu);
            }
         fos.close();
        fos = null;
  //                   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  //                   int next = is.read();
  //                   while (next > -1) {
  //                       bos.write(next);
  //                       next = is.read();
  //                   } 
  //                   bos.flush(); 
  //                   byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
  //                   bos.close();
  //                   bos = null;
                Bitmap tempBitmap =     
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
  //Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
               //result = null;
               bmImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempBitmap, 150, 180, true);
               tempBitmap.recycle();
               tempBitmap = null;
 // bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
              // Log.i("Byte Array Size", ":"+byteArrayBuffer.length());
              // bis.close();
               is.close();
             //  bis = null;
               is = null;
               return bmImg;
          } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
          }

     }

   }
```